# When increasing resolution all GUI text and buttons etc gets larger

Tags: awesome-wm

I'll show you three examples where you see the increase in size due to the text in the terminal.
I change the res with xrandr, the pic1 has 800x600 and seems OK, then in pic2 I changed res to
1856x1392 and it also seems OK but after I restart awesome I get the thing in pic3.

I have not even after 3 weeks found the solution to this so I'm stumped.
What can I do?

```
https://ibb.co/JktWWSR
https://ibb.co/vkKtsf3
https://ibb.co/xLCH97c
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a different DPI value is detected after the change.

There are a couple of sources Awesome asks to determine a DPI value to use.

- Users can explicitly assign a DPI value to a screen (`s.dpi = 42`).
- By default, AwesomeWM uses the following chain to detect a DPI value:

  - The value `Xft.dpi` from the X resource database: `awesome-client 'return awesome.xrdb_get_value("", "Xft.dpi")'`
  - The size of the root window as reported by the X11 server (size in px and size in mm allows to compute a DPI): `awesome-client 'return require("gears.debug").dump_return{size = {root.size()}, size_mm = {root.size_mm()}}'`
- Do you set `auto_dpi_enabled` anywhere in your config?

  - If so... uhm, I am not quite sure currently what values are used. I think it tries to get the numbers from RandR.

Anyway, the following command should produce the DPI value that AwesomeWM settled on:
`awesome-client 'local res = {} for s in screen do res[s] = s.dpi end return require("gears.debug").dump_return(res)'`

Sorry, this answer is very much not an answer. However, your question is also more of a bug report than a question... sorry.

Comment: Thank you :D
I found out that when I set the resolution with xrandr I need to also set the DPI to whatever I need it to be.
I tried 48, but that was small and those eyes is not with me anymore :P
but DPI at 96 seems OK.

So much thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

//TD